# How can I simplify my game enemy spawning algorithm? (code snippet included)

Tags: javascript

I have a hero character in the middle of the screen and I want to spawn zombies all around him in random positions but some distance away from him. `heroDistance` defines this distance.

It does not matter if they are pushed outside the boundaries of the screen when they are spawned, they all come towards him. It would not matter if this did not happen, but it just seemed easier.

At the moment the random location of the zombie is created for the x axis with `random(screenWidth)` and y axis `random(screenHeight)`, and those values are fed into the `spawnLocation` function that depending on where they are in relation to the hero are either increased or decreased to move they away.

My code seems far too verbose, even though I have worked really hard on it. Am I missing some obvious technique to make it simpler?

```js
const state = {
  options: {
    numberOfZombies: 10,
  },
  characters: {
    hero: {
      xPosition: 150,
      yPosition: 150,
    },
  },
};

const screenWidth = 400;
const screenHeight = 400;

const random = range => Math.floor(Math.random() * range);

function createZombies(state) {
  const heroDistance = 10;
  const spawnLocation = (zomPos, heroPos, axisLength) => {
    return zomPos > heroPos
      ? zomPos + axisLength / heroDistance
      : zomPos - axisLength / heroDistance;
  };

  for (let index = 0; index < state.options.numberOfZombies; index += 1) {
    console.log({
      xPosition: spawnLocation(
        random(screenWidth),
        state.characters.hero.xPosition,
        screenWidth,
      ),
      yPosition: spawnLocation(
        random(screenHeight),
        state.characters.hero.yPosition,
        screenHeight,
      ),
    });
  }
}

createZombies(state);
```

Comment: You could try here as well: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ Seems more appropriate

Comment: I thought about it, but I think it is relevant to ask how to improve code here? It is not really subjective, if I can do it in less lines and easier to understand then everyone should share that knowledge.

Comment: And you are more likely to get answers... ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generate a random angle and radius, and then transform these values into Cartesian coordinates.

```
let theta = Math.random() * (2 * Math.PI)
let r = Math.random() * variationInR + minimumR

let zombieX = Math.cos(theta) * r + heroX
let zombieY = Math.sin(theta) * r + heroY
```

If you want these to be integers, then make them so. This generates zombies uniformly radially from the hero at least `minimumR` units away (Pythagorean distance). If you want to maintain the Manhattan distance behavior, then generate your `dX` and `dY` and add them to the hero's position.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! There is a small typo, it should be Math.random()